# Android Studio 3.0.1 NDK fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory

Tags: android-ndk, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

My Application having native code was running perfect with previous Android Studio version. I just Updated to **3.0.1** and getting this error

```
/Users/salman.nazir/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h    
fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
```

I checked the directory, stdint.h file is there in the mentioned path. Should i need to set something to get that file accessed?

**Note**: I am using MacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just remove the `ndk-bundle` (latest version 16) folder from the SDK folder and put there older NDK version (15c). I downloaded the previous ndk version [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html).

It seems to be problem with the latest NDK. So far, this is the hack for me to  proceed.

Comment: NDK r16 deprecates **gcc**, try using **clang** toolchain. If you set the compiler in **Application.mk**, this means that you should remove `NDK_TOOLCHAIN` or `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION`. For **CMakeLists.txt**, don't set `ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN`.

Answer (score 1):

The error says, that the cross-toolchain (e.g. gcc) cannot find the STL (aka libstdc++6) headers.

A closer look into [Android Developer Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/09/introducing-android-native-development.html) reveals why.

The file in `~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h` redirects to a platform header and is not the actual header file.

[Edit]

- Here's how to use the new [unified headers](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-release-r16/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md#supporting-unified-headers-in-your-build-system) replacing the platform headers.
- And some [further information](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-release-r16/docs/UnifiedHeadersMigration.md) about this topic.